# Can an USB port be slower for not being properly plugged to the mobo?

Tags: usb, desktop-computer, computer-building

A while ago, I built my own PC from scratch, and assembled it myself. When I was assembling it, the cable that connected the USB ports on top of the case was almost too short, so I had to stretch it to the max so it could plug correctly.

What I'm wondering is: can these USB ports be "slower" or somehow impaired for not being properly plugged? They work just fine, but sometimes I feel like their transfer speed is very, very slow.

Thank you very much!

Comment: You could do some USB benchmarks ... [USB3Test Test software for your PassMark USB 3.0 loopback plug](https://www.passmark.com/products/usb3test.htm)

Comment: Check the manual that comes with your motherboard to identify what type of USB ports they are. Not all USB connectors on the motherboard are the same. Usually those that you plug in are USB 2.0 or maybe even 1.1? Also, the case itself might be having older version ports, so check their specs too. Note that the fixed USB ports at the back of the motherboard/pc will usually have the faster ports which could be 3.0. Again, the manual will tell you which ones they are. USB 3.0 can be identified by a blue colored bar when looking at the port itself.

Comment: Connections are kind of a "binary" thing--they're either connected or they're not.  If stretching damaged a connection so that it's intermittent, it should be intermittent all the time if it's internal because things aren't moving around.  You describe that things work fine, they're just slow.  (cont'd)

Comment: I can envision one problem that could manifest as you describe.  USB3 contains USB2 plus some additional connections for the high-speed data transfer.  If stretching things damaged one or more of the high-speed data lines and nothing else, USB3 devices would connect as USB2 and you would see USB2 data transfer speeds.  They're much slower than USB3, but not "very very" slow; people use USB 2.0 external drives and they're effective at that speed.